# Updating MySQL Error but nothing is wrong in code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I get this error:

Problem updating record. MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE KittenID = '2''

But then in my code:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Modify']))
{ 
            $connection = mysql_connect("Deleted the login info");

            // Check connection
            if (!$connection)
     {
         echo "Connection failed: " . mysql_connect_error();
     }
            else
            {
                //select a database
                $dbName="Katz";
                $db_selected = mysql_select_db($dbName, $connection); 
        
                //confirm connection to database
                if (!$db_selected)
                {
                    die ('Can\'t use $dbName : ' . mysql_error());
                }
                else
                {

                $KittenID = $_POST["KittenID"];
    $KittenAge = $_POST['KittenAge'];
    $Name = $_POST['Name'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Gender = $_POST['Gender'];
    $Personality = $_POST['Personality'];
    $Activity = $_POST['Activity'];
    $Comments = $_POST['Comments'];

                $query = "UPDATE Kittenzz 
                          SET KittenID = '$KittenID', 
                              KittenAge = '$KittenAge',
         Name = '$Name',
         Email = '$Email',
         Gender = '$Gender',
         Personality = '$Personality',
         Activity = '$Activity',
         Comments = '$Comments',
                          WHERE KittenID = '$KittenID'";

                $res = mysql_query($query);
                   
                if ($res)
                {
                   echo "<p>Record Updated<p>";
                }   
     else
     {
        echo "Problem updating record. MySQL Error: " . mysql_error();
     }
    }
            }
            mysql_close($connection);
}
        ?>
```

It makes no sense, I've read those lines of code for an hour, I cannot see the problem. It should run. Can anyone lend me fresh eyes?

Comment: remove comma after $Comments on your update query

Comment: Try your query in phpmyadmin if possible

Comment: You should never use user input directly in sql queries without at least using an escaping function first, eg mysql_real_escape_string().  Ideally you should not be using mysql_* functions any more for new code as they have been deprecated for years and should instead look at using either mysqli_* functions or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the comma near `'$comments'`

```
 $query = "UPDATE Kittenzz 
                          SET KittenID = '$KittenID', 
                              KittenAge = '$KittenAge',
                              Name = '$Name',
                              Email = '$Email',
                              Gender = '$Gender',
                              Personality = '$Personality',
                              Activity = '$Activity',
                              Comments = '$Comments'
                          WHERE KittenID = '$KittenID'";
```

Answer (score 0):

it may possible that in connection **username** and **password** in required.
like this :-

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

Comment: It is, but i deleted that info, in fact the problem was a comma missplaced. Problem solved, see answer up there.